# The removeEventListener does not stop the event for being launched

Tags: javascript, removeeventlistener

I know this has been already asked several times but I'm unable to make it work trying the different solutions proposed.

I have a div acting as button which basically spin a wheel and the spin duration depends on how long the button is pressed. So, I’m using `mousedown` and `mouseup` `eventListener` to measure the time and then launch the animation.
Everything is working fine but I would like to avoid the user pressing the spin button while the animation is running.  For that, I would like to remove the `mousedown eventListener` and add it again at the end of the animation.

This is the part f the code I came with but the `removeEventListener` is not working. I still can click on the button and the wheel start spinning again even if the previous transition is not finished. Please note I have removed the second addEventListener from the transitionend and I can still click on the button.

```
const spin = document.getElementById("spin")

function start() {
    // some stuff
    spin.removeEventListener("mousedown", start)
}

spin.addEventListener("mousedown", start)
```

Any ideas?

Please find bellow the full code:

```
const spin = document.getElementById("spin")
const ruleta = document.querySelector(".svg-ruleta")
const premio = document.querySelector(".premio")
const progreso = document.querySelector(".progreso")

const arrayPremios = [100,50, 10, 75, 25, 10, 75, 10, 50, 25, 10, 25]

var rotation = 0
var start_time
var id
var progress = 1

function start() {
    start_time = new Date()
    progress = 1
    id = setInterval(progressBar, 40)
    spin.removeEventListener("mousedown", start)
}

function end() {
    var now = new Date()
    progress = 0
    clearInterval(id)
    return now-start_time
}

function progressBar() {
    if(progress == 1){
        progreso.style.height = (progreso.offsetHeight - 5) + "px"
    }
}

spin.addEventListener("mousedown", start)

spin.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
    const pushTime = Math.min(end(),4000)
    console.log("Enlapsed time = "+pushTime)
    rotation += 4 + pushTime/1000 + Math.random() / 4
    console.log("Rotation  = "+rotation)
    ruleta.style.transform= "rotate("+rotation+"turn)"
    
})

ruleta.addEventListener("transitionend", () => {
    resultado = Math.trunc(( (rotation + 15/360) - Math.trunc((rotation + 15/360)))*12)
    progreso.style.height = "100%"
    premio.innerHTML = arrayPremios[resultado]
    spin.addEventListener("mousedown", start)
})
```

Many thanks.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Describe the problem**. "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it."_

Comment: Please add a [mcve] because that should work: https://jsfiddle.net/2rd4L6og/

Comment: The only reasons this wouldn't remove the event handler is if `// some stuff` throws an error or if `start` inside the handler doesn't refer to the function object. How do you know that "it doesn't work"? What happens and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Also removing a eventListener sounds like an antipattern. If you do not want it to react, set a state and don't do some stuff if the state is true

Comment: @mplungjan it's not an antipattern at all, it's not uncommon to want what the OP is doing here and have an event listener only fire once. However I should point out that rather than doing this manually, the [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method takes a "once" key in its optional `options` argument that if set to `true` will do this for you (see MDN documentation that I linked to).

Comment: In this case OP likely wants to allow them to spin again after the animation. I mostly see this pattern and it is unnecessary in my opinion

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I know the remove event is not working as I still can click the button and the eventListener is executed.

Comment: You are binding the event handler again in the `transitionend` event handler, which probably runs pretty sooner after releasing the mouse button?

Comment: It's what I want. The goal is to disable the event during the transition and re-enable it at the end of the transition. Transition takes a few seconds so I'm able to see if it's working or not. And even when I remove the line to re-enable on the transitionend function, I can see the remove event not working.